# How to set up Nimble server without WMSpanel?

Tags: linux, rtsp, live-streaming, transcoding, nimble

i can't figure it out, how to configure nimble server, there is lack of information/examples about: Setting my own Nimble server.

**Scenario:**

- IP camera which streams live RTSP h.256 video.
- Transmux/transport it, through my own Nimble Server.
- And pass to end-user as mpeg-dash video.

**I have done:**

- Installed Nimble server on Centos 7.
- Disabled panel section from /etc/nimble/nimble.conf.
- Followed tutorial section 2(example) link - [link](http://blog.wmspanel.com/2013/07/nimble-configs-explained.html). (Did not work).
- Installed required tools.
- Nimble Server works `service nimble status` response: `active` no errors.

**Questions:**

1. Is there any test example available or tutorial?
2. How should look /etc/nimble/nimble.conf file without WMSpanel?
3. How should look /etc/nimble/rules.conf file without WMSpanel? Or how does it work?
4. Is there any open source project from github?

Thanks, any help would by good.

Comment: once you make update in the rules.conf . you need to restart the service. anyway workaround for this proble?

Answer (score 3):

Here are the steps for manually configuration of nimble streamer without wmspanel :-

1) First of all you need basic subscription of wmspanel, for that you have to create free account using unique email address..
2) Then you have to open https://wmspanel.com/server and click on add Existing server link..
3) just copy and paste below configuration there :-

```
/* please do not modify this file, all changes will be overwritten by wmspanel agent */
{"SyncResponse":   {"status":"success","StreamCheckerMode":false,"UniqueVisitors":true,"RoutesHash":"1470659102671","Routes":[],"IpRanges":[],"ServerAuthorizationProperties":{"ServerAuthPropertiesHash":"0"},"CamerasHash":"","Cameras":[],"StreamsHash":"","Streams":[],"RtmpSettings":{"hash":"1470658699568","interfaces":[],"login":"","password":"","duration":6,"chunk_count":4,"dash_template":"TIME","protocols":["HLS","DASH"],"apps":[],"abr":[]},"RtspSettings":{"hash":"","interfaces":[]},"LivePullSettings":{"hash":"","streams":[]},"RtmpPublishSettings":{"hash":"","settings":[]},"RtspPublishSettings":{"hash":"","settings":[]},"HlsDRMSettings": {"hash": "0", "url": "", "key": "", "KeyServerSettings": {}},"HttpOriginApps":{"hash":"0","apps":[]},"AkamaiSettings":{"hash":"0","settings":[]},"Aliases":{"hash":"0","settings":[]},"DataSlicesInfo":{"hash":"1","data_slices":[{"id":"19215","tz":0}]},"UDPSenderSettings":{"hash":"0","settings":[]},"PayPerPublishSettings":{"hash": "0","url": "","auth_group_interval": 500,"apps":[]},"DvrSettings":{"hash":"0","settings":[]},"UserAgentGroupSettings":{"hash":"0","settings":[]},"RefererGroupSettings":{"hash":"0","settings":[]},"VideoEncodersInfo":{"hash":"0","encoders":[]},"AudioEncodersInfo":{"hash":"0","encoders":[]},"ServerSettings":{"MaxCacheSize":128,"MaxFileCacheSize":4096,"LogMode":"info"}}}
```

4) Restart nimble streaming service
5) Put your videos in physical drive(e.g. D:\videos)
6) Now change your rules.config file routes to "Routes":[["","/vod/","file://D:\video\",""]]
7) Now https://wmspanel.com/server and remove all the added rotes added previously..
8) Remove server too..and restart service..
9) that's it...Test your stream video at(http://demo.jwplayer.com/stream-tester/)

10) video link should be http://127.0.0.1:8081/vod/sample.mp4/playlist.m3u8 or http://:/vod/sample.mp4/playlist.m3u8

Comment: once you make update in the rules.conf . you need to restart the service. anyway workaround for this proble?

Answer (score 2):

The best way is to configure Nimble through WMSPanel and then remove it from your account. The resulting routes config will be what you need. You may then restart Nimble with API call.

Of course, I recommend making some basic WMSPanel subscription to be able to configure Nimble conveniently, get nice stats and be able to get help from the development team too: https://wmspanel.com/nimble/tco
But that's up to you, of course, as Nimble is a freeware anyway.

Comment: once you make update in the rules.conf . you need to restart the service. anyway workaround for this proble?

Comment: Sorry, you need to do the restart.

Comment: You can now apply rules configuration using this API method https://wmspanel.com/nimble/api#toggler=10

Comment: even after upgrading nimble to latest version.. gets 404 for manage/reload_config

Comment: Please check tour steps for enabling API, especially port etc. In case of questions contact our team via https://wmspanel.com/help

Answer (score 0):

New answer, as situation has changed since Mar 2023 - ver 4.x and above - they are not allowing running the server for free without the panel. so the answer is that you can't. unless you use version 3.X